# How do i fetch search result of two websites on my page?

Tags: php

I am creating a search result comparing site. In which you search a query and it show results of it from two websites at same time in two columns.

These are the sites banggood.com and gearbest.com so when people will search on my website it will show results from these two websites.

I am trying with this code (got it from stackoverflow member)

```
<form method="get" action="url_look.php">
 <input type="text" name="keywords"/>
 <input type="submit"  value="submit"/>
 </form>
```

**url_look.php**

```
require_once('uploads/simple_html_dom.php');
$keywords = str_replace(" ","-",$_GET['keywords']);
$url =  "http://www.banggood.com/search/$keywords.html";
$html = file_get_html($url);
echo "<ul>";
foreach($html->find('span[class=title]') as $product_title){
//for more details visit http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.html
echo "<li>".$product_title."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

But this is not working fully. Can anybody help me by improving this code to show result for both sites? inclduing images and prices.

Comment: Define "not working FULLY"...?

Comment: define was is the output of $html->find('span[class=title]')